# Does Nexus Repository OSS 3.x has site repository?

Tags: maven

I just compared two OSS versions(2.x, 3.x) of Nexus Repository.

I found 2.x has site repository.

Does 3.x also has repository for Maven site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NXRM3, we created the Raw repository to handle site as well as any repository needs not met by Sonatype supported formats.

Raw repositories act the same as other formats' repositories, with the hosted, proxy and group formats, except they are not bound to any format or tool usage or convention.  You can read more about Raw repositories in general [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Raw+Repositories+and+Maven+Sites).